# How can I take inverse Fourier transform of an image twice?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to apply the inverse discrete Fourier transform on the image twice. For this I did the following:

```
img = cv2.imread("a.png", 0)
img_back = cv2.idft(cv2.idft(img))
cv2.imwrite("f.png", img_back)
```

But I get an error saying:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test2.py", line 26, in <module>
    img_back = cv2.idft(cv2.idft(img))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/core/src/dxt.cpp:3335: error: (-215:Assertion failed) type == CV_32FC1 || type == CV_32FC2 || type == CV_64FC1 || type == CV_64FC2 in function 'dft'
```

I cannot understand the reason for this. How could I take the inverse fourier transform of the image twice?

Comment: have you tried `img_back = cv2.idft(cv2.idft[img])` ? From the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaa708aa2d2e57a508f968eb0f69aa5ff1)

Comment: @DrBwts That makes no sense, square brackets are for indexing, not for calling a function.

Comment: Why do you want to do the idft twice? What is the purpose of that?  What do you achieve from it?

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that the input to the `idft` function must be 32-bit or 64-bit float, with one or two channels (complex data is represented as two channels).

This error happens because `img` is an integer type (as expected because you read it in from a PNG file). To correct it, convert it to a floating-point type:

```py
img = cv2.imread("a.png", 0)
img = img.astype('f')
img_back = cv2.idft(cv2.idft(img))
```